# How to compare file names in SHELL SCRIPT

Tags: python, shell, unix

I have two file names as

```sh
file1 = "my_random_forest_2021-08-11-094538.csv.zip"
file2 = "my_random_forest_2021-08-11-094538.csv.zip"

if [$file1 == $file2]; then
    echo "matched"
```

On executing the script it says:

```
test.sh: line 5: [my_random_forest_2021-08-11-094538.csv.zip: command not found
```

How to compare file names that comes with the above mentioned formats?

Comment: If this is really POSIX shell, you also (aside from the lacking white space) need to use `= ` as operator, not `==`. See _man test_ for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ "$file1" = "$file2" ]; then
echo "matched";
fi
```

You're missing a space between the square bracket and the variable name. Without the space the shell is interpreting "[my_random_forest_2021-08-11-094538.csv.zip" as a command (which doesn't exist).

Comment: @JamesSchultz : Shouldn't it be `[ "$file1" = $file2" ]` ? At least according to _man test_, your version is not allowed.

Comment: You're right, I've updated the answer accordingly. It works in bash and zsh so despite not being documented so I didn't notice. It fails in sh though it does make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax would be like this

```
file1="my_random_forest_2021-08-11-094538.csv.zip"
file2="my_random_forest_2021-08-11-094538.csv.zip"
if [ $file1 = $file2 ] 
then
    echo "matched"
fi
```

There is no whitespace while declaring a variable.
There should be whilespace between variables and square brackets.
`;` is not neccesory after if. if you want to add if and then in one line you can add`;`
Matching will be done using `=` not `==`.
`if` should be ended with `fi` to close the statement.